# Parametrising the intersection of a double cone and a plane?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, conic-sections, parametric, parametrization, hyperbolic-functions

As the title states, I am struggling to parametrise the hyperbola resulting from intersection of a double cone and a plane. The equation of the cone is given as $z^2=x^2+y^2$ and the equation of the plane is $x+y=1$.

EDIT: I am stuck once I have some expressions for z.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I have gotten as far as $z^2=1-2xy$ and $z^2=2x^2-2x+1=(x-\frac{1+i}2)(x-\frac{1-i}2)$.

Thank you, Robert.

Comment: Try $z^2=x^2+(1-x)^2$.

Comment: Thank you! So then you have two factors of $z^2$ expressed in x with some imaginary part?

Comment: What's wrong with $z=\pm\sqrt{2x^2-2x+1}$?

Comment: Geogebra gives $(\frac12+\frac12\sinh{t},\frac12-\frac12\sinh{t},\mp\frac1{\sqrt{2}}\cosh{t}).$

Answer (score 1):

The algebraic equation of the cone is

$ r^T Q r = 0 $

where $r =[x, y, z]^T $ and

$Q = \begin{bmatrix} 1 && 0 && 0 \\ 0 && 1 && 0 \\ 0 && 0 && - 1\end{bmatrix} $

The algebraic equation of the plane is

$ n^T (r - r_0) = 0 $

where $n = [1, 1, 0] $ and $r_0$ is any point on the plane, so I'll take it as
$r_0=  [1, 0, 0]$

From this algebraic equation, we can generate the vector equation of the plane by finding two mutually orthogonal **unit** vectors that span the plane, an obvious choice is

$u_1 = [0, 0, 1]^T $ and $u_2 = [1, -1, 0]^T / \sqrt{2} $

So now the vector equation of the plane is

$ r = r_0 + u u_1 + v u_2  = r_0 + U w $

where $U = [u1, u2] $ and $w = [u, v]^T $

Plug this vector expression for $r$ into the algebraic equation of the cone,
you get,

$ (r_0 + U w )^T Q (r_0 + U w) = 0 $

Everything here is constant except the two entries of vector $w$.

Expand the above expression,

$ w^T U^T Q U w + 2 w^T U^T Q r_0 + r_0^T Q r_0 = 0 $

Direct evaluation gives us,

$A = U^T Q U = \begin{bmatrix} -1 && 0 \\ 0 && 1 \end{bmatrix} $

$b = U^T Q r_0 = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \end{bmatrix} $

$c = r_0^T Q r_0 = 1 $

So our algebraic equation of the intersection is now

$ w^T A w + 2 w^T b + c = 0 $

To find the center of this conic, use the following formula

$ w_0 = - \dfrac{1}{2} A^{-1}(2 b ) = - A^{-1} b = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ - \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \end{bmatrix} $

And with this center, we can write the above equation as

$ (w - w_0)^T A (w - w_0) + c - w_0^T A w_0 = 0 $

Now $c - w_0^T A w_0 = 1 - \dfrac{1}{2} = \dfrac{1}{2} $

And now we have

$ (w - w_0)^T A (w - w_0) = -\dfrac{1}{2} $

Dividing through by $(-\dfrac{1}{2}) $ results in

$ (w - w_0)^T E (w - w_0 ) = 1 $

where $E = -\dfrac{1}{2} A = \begin{bmatrix} 2 && 0 \\ 0 && - 2 \end{bmatrix} $

Matrix E is already diagonal, so now define the vector $v = w - w_0$ then

$ 2 v_1^2 - 2 v_2^2 = 1 \hspace{25pt} (*)$

And this the equation of a hyperbola that opens in both directions along the $v_1$ axis which is $ w_1$ axis (i.e. along $u_1$ ).

The standard parameterization for the hyperbola $(*)$ is

$ v_1 = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \sec t, \hspace{25pt} v_2 = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \tan t \hspace{25pt} t \in \mathbb{R} $

Recalling the relation between $v$ and $w$, we deduce that

$ w_1 = v_1 = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \sec t $ , and

$ w_2 = -\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} + \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \tan t $

Finally, the position vector $r = r_0 + U w $, so $r$ is given by

$ r = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix} 0 && \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\ 0 && -\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\ 1 && 0 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \sec t \\ -\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} + \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \tan t \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} \dfrac{1 + \tan t }{2} \\ \dfrac{1 - \tan t }{2} \\ \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \sec t \end{bmatrix}$

And this is a parameterization of the hyperbola of intersection.